# HAAR cascade training stuck in the middle

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, haar-classifier, haar-wavelet

I have 9768 positive images and 18050 negative images. At stage 2 I think it is stuck now more than 10 hours. I have already spent one day training. I don't want to waste that by closing the training.. Is it normal for this kind of behavior in the program.
[image]

Comment: Is it training the negative images? are they small?

Comment: training images are 18050 . I did not get what do you mean by small images?

Comment: maybe there is no more classifier with 0.995 hit rate found? Can you try to reduce minHitRate?

Comment: better reduce numPos, it will consume some after each stage (unless there is 100% hit rate). Try 9000 or 8500 for 0.995 minHitRate